# How to avoid try-catch when validating text input

Tags: java, try-catch

While working on a code, I was wondering if I could avoid try n catch and used something else. For example, if i have a value(from console) of type **double** and if user enters a string or something else then there should be a prompt to re-enter the value.

I know this can be done very easily using try-n-catch but how can we do it without it, is there any way out?

Please give an example if possible.

Comment: What's the problem with the question? Throwing exceptions is expensive. The question is asking how to avoid getting exceptions thrown when parsing invalid values. (I would agree if the question were *generally* about coding without using exceptions, but the text is clear about the specific use-case, which is perfectly valid.)

Comment: Are you asking about the wisdom if avoiding try/catch in general or the specific case of parsing a double from a string?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend handcoding `double` validation. It's quite a roundabout way of second-guessing `parseDouble`s result, and it's complex. There's scientific notation, four different limits to check, ...

Comment: i am wondering, if I could use  hasNext to validate the double input. Please advise!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sadly, the JDK lacks the `TryParse` method that some other libraries provide. I wouldn't be surprised to find something in [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/) or [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) that does it.

Alternately, you might use a `Scanner` and use its [`hasNextDouble`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextDouble%28%29) to do the check.

---

If you're asking how to avoid dealing with exceptions *in general*: Don't try. Exceptions are a powerful way of handling exceptional conditions in programs, and the "handle-or-declare" provided by checked exceptions (e.g., your code must handle the exception, or declare that it doesn't) is very useful.

But there are some use-cases, like your example, where you might well want to avoid an exception being thrown because, after all, a user entering invalid input isn't an exceptional condition, it's an all-too-common one. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Throw Exceptions are less robust but a good way to deal avoiding with try/catch statements.

```
 import java.io.*;

 public class UsingThrows { 
 public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException { 

 FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("def.txt");
 System.out.println("OK 1"); 

  }
 }
```

Comment: this is a good way indeed
but i don't want to use exceptions at all, any other alternative?